# How to write test cases for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bdd, testcase

I have `Rails Application` which uses `JavaScript Extensively`.

I would like to know is there any tool `(Similar to Rspec, Cucumber For Rails)`using which i can test the JS Code Written in my application.

What is the best practice to ensure that your JS is proper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several JavaScript unit testing tools. Among the ones I have used are:

- [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/)
- [JSUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit)
- [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/)

Web searches for these will turn up lots of comparisons, tutorials, and other articles about using them. There's an article [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine) on using Jasmine with Rails.

There's a nice article [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/javascript_testing) comparing several JavaScript testing suites for use with Rails.

Answer (score 3):

use jasmine.

http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/

and combine it with jTestDrive to test different browsers.
http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/

jasmine is used for the test cases and jsTestDrive is used for executing the tests on diffrent browsers.

Fell free to ask if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

You can try jasminerice gem git link  https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice